# Excel 2007 VBA Error #450 - Solver Addin

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have created a macro that works perfectly in 2010 but when I try to run 2007 it pops up an error message "Run-time error '450' Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment'. I'm solver addin integration- I have attached the excel file - In that sheet called "Multilinesup" and the macro button is "Run Optimizer".

Please help.

http://excelbyjoe.com/MEF/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/MLB-Optimal-lineups-v3-2007.xlsm

The Problem is SolverOk code

Please help

Comment: Can you post your code in the question please?

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush - Its really a big code and forum not allowing me to paste the entire code so here is the exact Code that Im stuck up with ' Application.Run "SolverOk", "$ak$2", 1, "0", "$g$2:$g$200", 2, "Simplex LP" '

Comment: Guys anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SolverOK` function takes [four arguments in Excel 2007](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257045(v=office.12).aspx) and [six arguments in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839427(v=office.14).aspx). The two additional arguments that it takes in Excel 2010 specify the solver engine. If you remove these arguments, it should work.

An alternative way to specify the Simplex LP engine is to set `SolverOptions AssumeLinear:=True`. This should work fine for both versions.

Comment: Sir Really Sorry but I'm not sure how to modify the code. This is the which I get error code ` Application.Run "SolverOk", "$ak$2", 1, "0", "$g$2:$g$200", 2, "Simplex LP" **` so mean to say it should be 'Application.Run "SolverOk", "$ak$2", 1, "0", "$g$2:$g$200, SolverOptions AssumeLinear:=True'  - Is that right

Comment: Change it to Application.Run "SolverOk", "$ak$2", 1, "0", "$g$2:$g$200".

Comment: then add SolverOptions AssumeLinear:=True in a different line.

Comment: I tried it but excel crashing and restarting - Any idea?

Comment: I have reinstalled office now its is working but some values comes up with #N/A. Please reply, We almost touched it, Please...

Comment: @ThiruSelvam I am travelling at the moment and have limited access to internet. The specific issue that you have has now been resolved, and your follow up question is about a new problem. I suggest you identify the problem, isolate it, try to solve it, and then ask for help, after you have described what you have tried and why it did not work. I did check the spreadsheet from your link, but in general you are supposed to isolate the problem and be ready to reproduce it with an example, which others can reproduce as well.

Comment: At any rate, posting a sheet with 38 modules and asking a question like "it crashes" or "it gives #N/A" discourages most people from answering. If you isolate the problem and demonstrate that you have tried to solve it, you will draw the attention of experts and then get good help. See also [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck and I hope you solve your issue! :)